# Magento call another action with parameters

Tags: controllers, redirect, action

While placing order I'm calling my custom saveOrderAction() where I'm saving order data.

Inside saveOrderAction(), I'm trying to call redirectAction() method where I want to fetch order information and redirect to paytm for payment.

Inside saveOrderAction() I've

```
  // redirectAction Call
                    if($response){
                        $this->_forward($action = 'redirectAction',
                            $controller = 'zigycheckout_index',
                            $module = 'Medex_ZigyCheckout',
                            $params = array('quote' => $checkoutSession->getQuote()));
                    }
```

which is not redirecting to redirectAction().
Also how I can fetch data in redirectAction() sent from saveOrderAction()? using `$order_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('quote');` ?

Comment: Please remove Action from $action = 'redirectAction'

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do this way

```
$parameters =array('test1'=>'data1','test2'=>'data2');
$this->_forward('redirect',NULL,NULL,$parameters);


public function redirectAction()
{
    $first_data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test1');
    $second_data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test2');
    .........More Code.........
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

```
$this->_forward($action = 'redirectAction',
         $controller = 'index',
         $module = 'zigycheckout',
         $params = array('quote' => $checkoutSession->getQuote()));
         }
```

The data is passed as parameters, so use the code as ,

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams('quote')
```

Answer (score 0):

There issue in format  of forward code:
Try this;

$this->_forward( `'redirect,'index','Medex_ZigyCheckoutRouterterIndenfire',array('quote_Id'=>$checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId()));`

You cannot send full object and suggest you send it quote id .

Comment: I tried `$this->_forward('redirect','index','zigycheckout', array('quote_Id'=>$checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId()));` but it didn't call that action.